# Mismatched types parameter error on rust generics

Tags: rust

expected type parameter `T`, found type parameter `A` error display. I have written lifetime implementation code also but it stills doesn't solve the problem. What's wrong I am doing?

```
fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = 5.0;
    let max_value = max(x, y);
    println!("The maximum value is {}", max_value); 
}

fn max<T: PartialOrd, A: PartialOrd>(x: T, y: A) -> T {
    if x > y {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}

// fn main() {
//     let x = 3;
//     let y = 5.0;
//     let max_value = max(&x, &y);
//     println!("The maximum value is {}", max_value); 
// }

// fn max<'a, T: PartialOrd + Copy, A: PartialOrd + Copy>(x: &'a T, y: &'a A) -> &'a T {
//     if x > y {
//         x
//     } else {
//         y
//     }
// }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4):

`T` and `A` do not have to be the same type, so you have two problems.

The first is that you constrain `T` and `A` to be `PartialOrd`, which is the same thing as `PartialOrd<Self>`.  So your actual constraints are `T: PartialOrd<T>, A: PartialOrd<A>`.  This means you can compare the order of `T`'s to other `T`'s and `A`'s to other `A`'s, but `x > y` compares a `T` to an `A`.

Instead, you need to constrain `T: PartialOrd<A>`.  (This also fails, but because of the invocation in `main()` -- more on that later.)

Second, the function is declared to return `T` but the `else` block returns `y`, which is not a `T`.  Rust is statically typed, so it expects the types to exactly match.

This could be fixed by requiring that `A` can be converted to `T` (that is, `A: Into<T>`) and then you can return `y.into()` from the `else` block.

So at this point, we have:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = 5.0;
    let max_value = max(x, y);
    println!("The maximum value is {}", max_value); 
}

fn max<T: PartialOrd<A>, A: Into<T>>(x: T, y: A) -> T {
    if x > y {
        x
    } else {
        y.into()
    }
}
```

But now you are left with more problems:

- There are no types `T` and `A` satisfying `T: PartialOrd<A>` where `T` is an integer and `A` is a float, therefore you cannot call this function with `3` and `5.0` as you do in `main()`.
- Likewise, there's no implementation of `Into<T>` on `A` for an integer type `T` and a float type `A`.
- `x > y` will *move* `x` and `y`, and then you cannot return them later.  This is trivially fixed by constraining both `T` and `A` to be `Copy`.

The second issue could be fixed by having an enum that means "either `T` or `A`" and returning that instead.  The `either` crate [has such a type called `Either`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html), which we can use here as `Either<T, A>`:

```
use either::Either;

fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = 5.0;
    let max_value = max(x, y);
    println!("The maximum value is {}", max_value); 
}

fn max<T: PartialOrd<A> + Copy, A: Copy>(x: T, y: A) -> Either<T, A> {
    if x > y {
        Either::Left(x)
    } else {
        Either::Right(y)
    }
}
```

(The `println!` works because `Either<T, A>` implements `Display` when both `T` and `A` do.)

You are still left with the problem where there's no built-in ordering implementation between integers and floats.

A "hail mary" solution could be to require that `T` and `A` can both be converted to `f64` and then convert `x` and `y` to `f64` before comparing them:

```
use either::Either;

fn main() {
    let x = 3;
    let y = 5.0;
    let max_value = max(x, y);
    println!("The maximum value is {}", max_value); 
}

fn max<T: Copy + Into<f64>, A: Copy + Into<f64>>(x: T, y: A) -> Either<T, A> {
    if x.into() > y.into() {
        Either::Left(x)
    } else {
        Either::Right(y)
    }
}
```

This is the first bit of code we have that actually compiles, and this might be good enough for your purposes.  There are still some issues that remain, however:

- `i64` and `u64` *cannot* be losslessy converted to `f64`, therefore they do not implement `Into<f64>`, and so if you change `let x = 3;` to `let x = 3u64;` (or `3i64`) compilation will again fail.
- `f64` does not implement `Ord` because it's possible for there to be two `f64` values `x` and `y` that are not equal but neither is greater than the other -- if either value is `NaN`, for example.  This won't cause your program to crash, but it may produce an unexpected or incorrect result.

I suspect that this is a learning exercise, so hopefully this answer helps you understand what is wrong with the original code.  I would not recommend a function like this in a real-world program; instead, it would be far better to convert both arguments to be of the same `Ord`-implementing type ahead of time and then you can use the built-in [`std::cmp::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.max.html) function (or [`Ord::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#method.max)).